# How to create a rebar repo?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I want to build and deploy erlang files which will then be used as a dependency in another project. Essentially I am looking for the equivalent of mvn deploy and a sonatype repo. How would I set this up with rebar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a dependency which rebar can understand, you need to have a `.app.src` file in a `src` directory. Take a look at [estring](https://github.com/dweldon/estring) - there I have the file `src/estring.app.src` along with my actual source file. In another project which requires estring I would have something like this in my rebar.config:

```
{deps, [{estring, ".", {git, "git://github.com/dweldon/estring.git", "HEAD"}},
...
```